# Trying to pull data from db using sqlite in perl by using multiple tables for filters

Tags: mysql, sqlite, perl

So I have previously done this by using a (what I consider complicated) string of IN statements in my SELECT statement... but I accidentally deleted my working files and lost my final product...and have since forgotten how to do it.

I'm looking for help recreating that statement, or trying it with JOIN....which I have zero idea how to do. (I know enough about programming to poke around and get something successful ~50% of the time.)

I am working with a database with three tables of interest.

Table 1 contains:
master_id, sub_id1, sub_id2

Table 2 contains:
sub_id, sub_sub_id1, sub_sub_id2

Table 3 contains:
sub_sub_id, data

Sorry in advance for the ambiguous data structure.  So the master_id consists of sub_id1 and sub_id2. sub_id1 and sub_id2 are identified as just plain sub_id's in table 2, consisting of sub_sub_id1 and sub_sub_id2. Sub_sub_id1 and 2 are identified as just sub_sub_id in table 3 with the relevant data I need.

What I am trying to do is pull all sub_sub_ids and data from table 3 when they exist in the tree of table 1.  (Not all sub_sub_id's exist outside of table 3.)

So if sub_sub_id from table 3 is found as either a sub_sub_id1 or sub_sub_id2 in table 2, and if that corresponding sub_id from table 2 is found as sub_id1 or sub_id2 in table 1, then get sub_sub_id and data from table 3.

To make matters more complicated, not every master_id has a sub_id2. And I only want to look in rows that have both sub_id1 and sub_id2.

I hope this makes some sort of sense and there is enough info to help! I'm traveling for work and away from all my handwritten scratch notes that got me through this problem last time. :(

Comment: Maybe:

SELECT tbl3.sub_sub_id 
FROM table3 tbl3
 INNER JOIN table2 tbl2
  ON tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl2.sub_sub_id1
 INNER JOIN table2 tbl2_1 
  ON tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl2.sub_sub_id2
 INNER JOIN table1 tbl1 
  ON tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl1.sub_id1 OR tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl1.sub_id2
WHERE tbl1.sub_id2 is not null;

Comment: Is the "table3 tbl3" redundancy a part of the FROM or JOIN statement?  Or does it just go in once between those?

Comment: or is one of those a placeholder for the merged table?

Comment: Not having any luck currently, but shouldn't: INNER JOIN table1 tbl1 ON tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl1.sub_id1 OR tbl3.sub_sub_id = tbl1.sub_id2" 

be: "INNER JOIN table1 tbl1 ON tbl2.sub_id = tbl1.sub_id1 OR tbl2_1.sub_id = tbl1.sub_id2 WHERE tbl1.sub_id2"

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. I tested it in sqlite version 3.11.0. If you use sqlite older than 3.8.3 (which don't understand the `WITH` clause) change `t1_can_be_used` and `t1_can_be_used` into real tables or views.

```
create table t1 as
  select 1 master_id, 10 sub_id1, 20   sub_id2 union
  select 2 master_id, 40 sub_id1, 50   sub_id2 union
  select 3 master_id, 30 sub_id1, null sub_id2 union
  select 4 master_id, 60 sub_id1, 70   sub_id2 union
  select 5 master_id, 80 sub_id1, 90   sub_id2;

create table t2 as
  select 10 sub_id, 100 sub_sub_id1, 200 sub_sub_id2 union
  select 20 sub_id, 300 sub_sub_id1, 400 sub_sub_id2 union
  select 30 sub_id, 500 sub_sub_id1, 600 sub_sub_id2 union
  select 35 sub_id, 700 sub_sub_id1, 300 sub_sub_id2;

create table t3 as
  select 100 sub_sub_id, 'ABC' data union
  select 200 sub_sub_id, 'QED' data union
  select 300 sub_sub_id, 'XYZ' data union
  select 400 sub_sub_id, 'WWW' data union
  select 500 sub_sub_id, 'CIA' data union
  select 600 sub_sub_id, 'KGB' data union
  select 700 sub_sub_id, 'FDR' data union
  select 800 sub_sub_id, 'JFK' data;

with
t1_can_be_used as (
  select * from t1
  where sub_id1 is not null
  and   sub_id2 is not null
),
t2_can_be_used as (
  select * from t2
  where sub_id in (
    select sub_id1 from t1_can_be_used union
    select sub_id2 from t1_can_be_used
  )
)
select * from t3
where sub_sub_id in (
  select sub_sub_id1 from t2_can_be_used union
  select sub_sub_id2 from t2_can_be_used
);
```